# Twilio odd Record verb behaviour, need advice

Tags: php, twilio

I have a phone-tree that enqueues a caller if they don't provide an extension, and while music is playing, the caller can press a key at anytime to leave a message.

If the user has an extension, and the agent does not pick up, it goes to  LeaveMessage.php, and hits the record verb just fine, and the caller can leave a message, and it adds to my database, and emails out. Works perfect.

The strange record verb behavior happens when I attempt to hit this same LeaveMessage.php script from a caller being redirected out of the queue. It simply skips over that Record verb, even though it works fine coming from anywhere else.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it behaves like this.

index.php

```
if( $_REQUEST['Digits'] ) {
    echo '<Redirect>./LeaveMessage.php?exten=' . $digits . '</Redirect>';
}
echo '<Say>Thank you for calling.</Say>';
echo '<Gather timeout="4">';
echo '<Say>If you know your parties extension, please enter it now.</Say>';
echo '<Say>If you do not know your parties extension, please hold while we connect you to an operator.</Say>';
echo '</Gather>';
//redirect to enqueue caller, and dialOut and event handlers.
echo '<Redirect>./EnqueueCaller.php</Redirect>';
```

LeaveMessage.php

```
echo '<Say>Please leave a message after the tone. </Say>';
echo '<Record action="./handle_message.php?exten=' . $exten . '" maxLength="35" method="POST" timeout="7" playBeep="true" />';
echo '<Gather action="./leave_a_message.php?exten=' . $exten . '" method="GET" >';
echo '<Say>I\'m sorry, the message was not received, press any key to try again.</Say>';
echo '</Gather>';
```

WaitQueue.php

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['Digits'] ) ) {
    echo '<Redirect>./leave_a_message.php</Redirect>';
    echo '</Response>';
    exit();
}
else if( isset( $_REQUEST['hold'] ) ) {
    echo '<Gather action="./wait.php?Digits=true" method="POST" numDigits="1" timeout="1">';
    echo '<Say>At any time press any number to leave a message, and an agent will call you back shortly.</Say>';
}
else {
    echo '<Say> You are now on hold.</Say>';
    echo '<Gather action="./wait.php?Digits=true" method="POST" numDigits="1" timeout="1">';
}
echo '<Say>At any time press any number to leave a message, and an agent will call you back shortly.</Say>';
echo '<Play>';
echo 'http://com.twilio.sounds.music.s3.amazonaws.com/ClockworkWaltz.mp3';
echo '</Play>';
echo '</Gather>';
echo '<Redirect>./wait.php?hold=true</Redirect>';
echo '</Response>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your issue here is that, in the situation the caller skips over the `<Record>` verb, your caller is still in the Queue. Whilst in the Queue, the user hears what is going on in the `waitUrl` and [you can only the use Play, Say, Pause, Hangup, Gather, Redirect and Leave verbs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue#attributes-waitUrl).

However, you are not out of luck. In order to record a message, you need the user to leave the queue by themselves and you can do so using the [`<Leave>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/leave). When you `<Leave>` a queue the call returns to the TwiML directly after the `<Enqueue>` verb, so you can add your `<Record>` TwiML there.

You didn't provide your EnqueueCaller.php file, but the idea is that your Enqueue could look like this:

```
<Response>
  <Enqueue>Queue Name</Enqueue>
  <Redirect>./leave_a_message.php</Redirect>
</Response>
```

And your WaitQueue.php would start with (note the `<Leave>` instead of the `<Redirect>`):

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['Digits'] ) ) {
    echo '<Leave/>';
    echo '</Response>';
    exit();
}
```

Alternatively, you could manually dequeue the user with the REST API and redirect them to the `<Record>` TwiML as the developer in [this question eventually did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883569/recording-a-voicemail-while-in-a-twilio-queue/34899801).

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

So, I think I got it now with your suggestion, I took it a step further and created an EnqeueCallerCallbackHandler for the enqueued caller, and then redirect under the 'leave' QueueResult.

I have to say though, regarding the enqueue verb, it's a bit unintuitive when using a redirect verb from a queue (and from my wait.php), it still considers the caller within that enqueue verb. I figured it was a "new page" more or less and you could then use whatever verbs you wanted. Oh well.

Cheers and thanks again! You Twilio folk are amazing.

Comment: Yeah, it's not phenomenally clear in the documentation, I had to look it up myself. Glad you're sorted though!