# Twilio redirect to record just hanging up instead

Tags: twilio, voice

I give the caller the ability to drop out of queue and leave a voicemail, however, when sent to the voicemail TWiML it plays the outgoing message, but doesnt play the beep or record, it just hangs up.  I see no errors in the console either.

If i set this page to be the voice answer page, it works as expected. Im losing my mind!

answer.asp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
<Say voice="woman">Thank you for calling . </Say>
<Say voice="woman">No notices</Say>
<Say voice="woman">Calls may be recorded for quality and training purposes.</Say>
<Say voice="woman">Please hold for a customer service representative. </Say>
<Enqueue method="GET" action=/voice/dequeue.asp" waitUrlMethod="GET" waitUrl="/voice/holdMusic.asp">CustomerService</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

entering hold queue and reloads approx every 20 seconds:
holdmusic.asp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Gather numDigits="1" action="/voice/quitHold.asp" method="GET">
<Say>You are number 1 of 1 in the queue. Expected hold time is under a minute. Press any key while on hold to leave a voicemail.</Say>
<Play>/voice/mp3s/quiet.mp3</Play>
</Gather>
<Redirect/>
</Response>
```

exceeding max hold time:

holdmusic.asp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Say voice="woman">Unfortuantely, we are experiencing long hold times and we are transferring you to voicemail.</Say>
<Redirect method="GET">/voice/quitHold.asp</Redirect>
</Response>
```

quithold.asp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
<Say voice="woman">You are leaving the hold queue and going to voicemail</Say>
<Say voice="woman">Please ree cord a message and we will return your call shortly. If you are calling after hours, we will return your call the next business day. </Say>
<Record finishOnKey="*" method="GET" action="/voice/hangup.asp" maxLength="60" playBeep="true" transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/voice/transcribe.asp" recordingStatusCallbackMethod="GET" recordingStatusCallback="/voice/voicemail.asp" trim="trim-silence" />
<Hangup/>   
</Response>
```

Comment: That is weird, the TwiML is valid and the attributes all look correct. I'm actually a little lost here. It might be best for you to get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and send them some Call SIDs for example calls where this happens.

Comment: I put in a support ticket. I just thought I would try here first and see if maybe I was missing something.

Comment: Fair enough. Nothing looks wrong to me there though, so perhaps there's more to it.

Comment: Thanks.  I added more TWiML for reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883569/recording-a-voicemail-while-in-a-twilio-queue

Comment: I'm lost, sorry! Hopefully support can look into this deeper and help you out.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same setup as you and am experiencing the same issue.